# Two images beneath each other QGridLayout PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to use a QGridLayout to structure my GUI. There need to be two images on top of each other, and I can only get the top one visible. I've made two QLabels, resized them to the proper size and set the QPixmap to the QLabel. After this I have set the labels at positions (1,1) and (2,1) however only the top one shows up. I'm new to PyQt4 and I don't really know how this happens. If I swap them the other one shows up so the images are reachable.

```
identifyLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

frontIdentifyImg = QtGui.QLabel()
frontIdentifyImgPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.realpath('../GUI/front_image_identify.png'))
frontIdentifyImg.resize(450,450)
frontIdentifyImg.setPixmap(frontIdentifyImgPixmap)
identifyLayout.addWidget(frontIdentifyImg, 1, 1)

frontMatchImg = QtGui.QLabel()
frontMatchImgPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.realpath('../GUI/front_image_match.png'))
frontMatchImg.resize(450,450)
frontMatchImg.setPixmap(frontMatchImgPixmap)
identifyLayout.addWidget(frontIdentifyImg, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, I added the wrong widget to the layout. Last line should have been:

```
identifyLayout.addWidget(frontMatchImg, 2, 1)
```

Plus the resizes are not necessary and the indexing starts at 0.